# How to run java class with main method in play framework1.x

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

My web application is developed in Play Framework 1.x and it contains a Java class with the main method, so I can run this main method in Play Framework 1.x version. Can  I run it in Play Framework 2.x using either run or runMain command of play task?

Answer (score 1):

from the book "play for java"

**Play wasn't based on Java Enterprise Edition APIs and made for Java Developers; Play is for Web developers**

we aren't use main method in play framework to run application. each request reach to application bind to action method of controller class (or it's subsets) and  action method do what she must do to handle request. if you want to execute main method you must declare route to it. if you want more information see the Documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaActions) and [there](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaRouting)